# How to specify an asp-action but don't render it in the URL

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

I have a controller:

```
public class StaffController
{
    [HttpGet("staff/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetStaffMembers(int id)
    {
        return View("Staff", new StaffViewModel(id));
    }
}
```

That I want to trigger from a link:

```
<a asp-controller="Staff" asp-action="GetStaffMembers" asp-route-id="@Model.Id">Click here for @Model.Id</a>
```

This is routing to `staff/getstaffmembers/1`

Using asp anchor attributes, how can I make this go to `staff/1`?

---

**Note:**
I'm already aware that I can use `<a href="/staff/@Model.Id" ...` and would like to find the correct syntax for `asp-*` attributes instead.

Comment: Url Routing need to be exactly match with the action method of controller. So, even if you change the URL, you may still need the action method matching to that URL.

Comment: @SonalBorkar: the URL does match the action method of a controller: `[HttpGet("myController/{id}")]`

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? For your current `StaffController`, it does not have the defination for `View`. If you create a built-in controller, it will be inherited from `Controller` like `public class StaffController:Controller`. For such controller, `<a asp-controller="Staff" asp-action="GetStaffMembers" asp-route-id="@Model.Id">` will create the expected route `staff/1`.

Comment: I don't have an isolated repro. Following the answer from @ChrisPratt below I have noticed that I am coming from a view/path that is loaded from a different controller. Perhaps this is the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. With an explicit route attribute applied to the action, this should not be happening. Essentially, it seems to be falling back to the default route. It's typical to define a route prefix on the controller-level, though, so perhaps doing that will sort it out:

```
[Route("staff")]
public class StaffController
{
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetStaffMembers(int id)
    {
        return View("Staff", new StaffViewModel(id));
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can simply give your route a name, and then explicitly reference it:

```
[HttpGet("staff/{id}", Name = "GetStaffMembers")]
```

Then:

```
<a asp-route="GetStaffMembers" asp-route-id="@Model.Id">...</a>
```

One last thing that might be the issue, which is sort of related to the first. Since your controller itself has no explicit route, it might not be find the relative route correctly. Making it absolute might help:

```
[HttpGet("~/staff/{id}")]
```

That essentially says make this route just `/staff/{id}` no matter what else is going on with routing or my controller.

Comment: Should not `[HttpGet("staff/{id}")]` been suffice? I have been using this and working fine.

Comment: It *should*, but obviously is not. I'm merely providing potential workarounds.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPratt -  I have tried these solutions without success. I have noticed that my link is generated on a page/path that uses a different controller. Could this be the cause?

Comment: Yep, when calling from the same controller I can use `asp-route`